# Issues with Decompressing Multipart zip with sub folders having Latin Accented characters on Linux server

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zip, unzip

I have a multipart zip file with thousands of sub folders. Some of the folders have Accented characters.

I first combine all the multipart files into one using :

```
for FILE in *.zip; do zip -FF $FILE --out target_folder/$FILE; done
```

Then I unzip them using

```
for FILE in *.zip; do unzip $FILE ; done
```

This is where i get the error. Any subfolder with Latin Accented char in them will have all the files as 0KB and with the below error.

> inflating: XXXXÉ00001/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.pdf   bad CRC 40fa81ef  (should be 64c1e1d8)

I manually unzipped the files on my laptop(windows 10) and no issues there.

Is there any thing that I can do to prevent this?

Comment: The fact that the filenames have accented characters will not have any impact on the CRC calculation - that calculation is done on the uncompresed data . Can you post an example zip file?

Comment: Probably best to post on [unix.se]. This is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. Note that this is explicitly called out in the [tag:linux] tag: "*NOTICE: All Linux questions must be related to programming*"